# How to identify concurrency issues in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, concurrency, oracle-enterprise-manager

For a short period in time we had a concurrency issue that lead to subsequent faults in our application (Java, Spring, Hibernate).

[image: concurrency]

<strike>Since we are using dictionary managed tablespaces,</strike> I first thought about too small sequence cache sizes, but we are using locally managed tablespaces. However, the top statement's sequence does have a sequence cache size of 1,000. Other frequently used sequences only have a cache size of 20.

Do you know a good starting point for further investigation?

Feel free to request more detailed statistics.

### Additional Information

```
Begin Snap: 19-Mrz-15 22:00:28, 525, 75.8
End Snap: 19-Mrz-15 22:30:48, 695, 43.9

Top 10 Foreground Events by Total Wait Time
-------------------------------------------

| Event                                    | Waits     | Total Wait Time (sec) | Wait Avg(ms) | % DB time | Wait Class  |
|------------------------------------------|-----------|-----------------------|--------------|-----------|-------------|
| cursor: mutex S                          | 2,966,994 | 18K                   | 6            | 18.8      | Concurrency |
| cursor: pin S wait on X                  | 5,515     | 17,1K                 | 3094         | 17.9      | Concurrency |
| library cache lock                       | 96,812    | 13,7K                 | 142          | 14.3      | Concurrency |
| latch: shared pool                       | 1,039     | 11,8K                 | 11314        | 12.3      | Concurrency |
| latch free                               | 7,105     | 7198                  | 1013         | 7.5       | Other       |
| library cache: mutex X                   | 151,055   | 6594,4                | 44           | 6.9       | Concurrency |
| log file sync                            | 463,819   | 5384,6                | 12           | 5.6       | Commit      |
| DB CPU                                   |           | 2859,4                |              | 3.0       |             |
| SGA: allocation forcing component growth | 92        | 1253,3                | 13623        | 1.3       | Other       |
| db file sequential read                  | 403,533   | 1139,1                | 3            | 1.2       | User I/O    |

Top Activity (anonymized)
-------------------------

11s4xj38uffuw | update [SESSIONDATA: no triggers, 4 b-tree indices] set [22 COLUMNS] where [ID]=:23
90wgukkg0du5c | select count(*) from [USER_SPECIFIC_DATA] where [OWNED_BY_USER, uses bindings]
d8da2d7yddqv9 | insert into [USER_SPECIFIC_DATA2]
```

I found out that for many tables in the top activity statements a histogram was created (`HEIGHT BALANCED` or `FREQUENCY`), possibly for [adaptive cursor sharing](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/why_are_there_more_cursors_in_11g_for_my_query_containing_bind_variables_1).

Comment: Oracle Wait Interface history events? Get the actual statement from the hash and then check it out?

Comment: Indexes, Triggers? What happened during that update?

Comment: `cursor: mutex S` is very often the sign of excessive hard (or even) parsing. Is your application using prepared statements ("bind variables")? And why are you using dictionary managed tablespaces? Oracle highly recommends to use locally managed tablespaces.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I haven't seen any top activity that does not use bind variables. Could it be an issue with adaptive cursor sharing? ... We are using locally managed tablespaces. My fault.